# Flex classes in Pure AS3 projects

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

According to this [blog article](http://flashauthoring.blogspot.com/2008/10/using-flex-webservice-component-in.html) , some Flex components such as the Flex WebService and HTTPService don't rely on the Flex framework, so it should be possible to import and use them in a pure AS3 project.

I often wonder if Adobe could have designed Flex with a modular approach similar to that of the Zend framework, whereby some of the classes could have been imported without having to load the full framework.

Do you know of any other Flex components/classes that could be used in such a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Flex Compiler--which is used in pure ActionScript projects compiled w/ Flash Builder--will optimize itself.  Only the classes you use go into the final SWF.  So, the final file size will no be affected if you put 100 classes in your library path and never use them.  So, feel free to add the Flex SWC information and just use the HTTPService and/or WebService.

I would assume if you are using Flash Pro that similar optimizations occur when creating the final SWF.

That said, Adobe does seem to be moving in the direction of separating out Flex.  Flex 4 classes, for example, are located across 10 different SWCs.  Mobile classes in Flex Hero are also isolated, adding at least one more SWC to the mix.

I suggest you take a look at the rpc.swc class, as I guess that is where the HTTPService and other related classes reside.

Comment: This is all true but be aware that for some silly reason the WebService and HTTPService depend on a lengthy list of Flex classes.  This doesn't prohibit them from being used in AS-Only projects but it does make the SWFs larger.  Also these classes do actually have some UI interactions (which actually cause the dependency bloat) that may not work in an AS-Only project.  For instance the busy cursors may not actually work.  But I'm not sure since I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: @James Ward thanks for the elaboration.  Although, I would not have expected cursor changes to have dependencies to the Flex Framework.  But I haven't reviewed the internal code myself.

Comment: The busy cursor in Flex is actually just an animated Sprite or something that gets added to the stage above everything else.  That is why when a large amount of xml gets parsed on the client, thus locking the Flash Player rendering thread, the busy cursor stops spinning.  :)

Answer (score -1):

The Text Layout Framework and OSMF are also part of the Flex framework but could be used in a pure AS3 project

Comment: TLF & OSMF clearly exist outside of the Flex framework, both are frameworks in their own right, not really parts of the Flex framework

Comment: TLF & OSMF are used by many of the Flex spark components (Label, RichText, Video, ...). But there are separated SWC, that can be used outside Flex, like the rpc.swc, so I thing it answers your question on this very point.
I know they are frameworks in their own, and can be downloaded without taking them directly from the Flex SDK, which is why they differ from the RPC lib.